# Replacing sink trap with a flexible one?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, sink

Bathroom sink was not properly installed. It is a little misaligned. I cannot align it appropriately because the **rigid**  trap pipe does not allow for it. I am thinking of replacing the P Trap ( only the U shaped pipe) with a flexible one.
Here is a picture:
[image]

1. Can I connect a flexible plastic P trap to both metal pipes? Or what is best material?
2. What else should I take in consideration when replacing the trap? And any product recommendation?

Here is a picture of how the sink is shifted to accommodate the pipes:
[image]

Comment: That is not mis aligned, the angle from the wall is not a problem it may just need a slight tweak to make sure the fittings are in line , please don't use flex it is the worst of all options. Flex is a great place to catch all the soap scrum and hair and create clogs many times faster than smothe wall pipe/ tubing.

Comment: Misaligned I can see in the pipe going to the sink, however that would depend on how misaligned the sink is on the vanity.

Comment: What you see right now is working fine but the sink itself is shifted to the left in order to allow the pipes to fit together. That's what is misaligned. A proper fit would be to move the sink half an inch to the right, and then the U Piper would not fit. I'll try to attach a better picture showing the whole thing

Comment: @EdBeal See the second photo that show the full picture of how the sink is shifted to the left, so the pipes can fit together. I know i can shift the cabinet to the left, but doing that would make it too close to the toilet.

Comment: You might get lucky with an ABS p trap that's subtly different, dimension-wise. Otherwise, just do over with ABS. Flex is a terrible solution.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate how about something like this https://www.amazon.com/Fernco-Inc-PFT-150-Flex-Rubber/dp/B000BQRY4S/

Comment: Fernco rubber trap looks very promising, as long as it isn't kinked when assembled. I would certainly try it.

Comment: I agree the fernco would be much better than the flex PVC "junk".

Comment: @EdBeal I ended up using it and it's been rocking so dar. Works great. Will see how long it will last

Comment: @awm, please provide and accept an answer below, or delete your question. Unresolved questions are ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a Fernco Inc. PFT-150 Flex Qwik Rubber Trap. It worked really well so far and allowed for a good amount of adjustment in such a way the sink sits in it's correct position. It's been about 7 months so far and no issues with clogging or leaking.

Answer (score 1):

You sure can attach the plastic flex to the metal. Just buy a complete trap kit and it will have all the nuts, pipe and washers needed to switch it out.

Another possible option is to try to twist the wall side of the pipe a little in the direction you need.